# Calculate percentage of interview participants who had education background

Tags: python, pandas

I am really sorry if this question was already asked. I have tried to search different answers but havent found one related to mine.

I have a large dataframe with data looking like this :

```
import pandas as pd
  
# intialise data of lists.
data = {'interview_key':['00-60-62-69', '00-80-63-65', '00-81-80-59', '00-87-72-75'],
        'any_education':['YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'NAN']}
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  
# Print the output.
df
```

This data represents a group of people who were interviewed and they agreed to have any education represented by **YES** or didnt have education at all represented by **NO**.

I want to do a simple task and that is to *find percentage of people who had any form of education*. in simple terms those who said YES to having any education.

How can this be done.

Comment: What is expected ouput from sample data?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['any_education'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

```
YES    0.50
NO     0.25
NaN    0.25
Name: any_education, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd

# initialise data of lists.
data = {'interview_key': ['00-60-62-69', '00-80-63-65', '00-81-80-59', '00-87-72-75'],
        'any_education': ['YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'NAN']}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Calculate percentage
total_yes = df['any_education'].value_counts()['YES']
total_rows = len(df.axes[0])
percentage = total_yes / total_rows * 100

# print the output
print(f"{percentage = }%")
```

Output:

```
percentage = 50.0%
```